# Calculating Stack memory being used on Java

Tags: java, memory-management, stack-overflow

I'm using drools and [activiti](http://activiti.org/) to evaluate some rules. The problem is that activiti uses recursion and i'm getting StackOverFlowError, when we have a lot of rules (this is not an infinite loop/recursion, increasing the stack size solves the problem).

1) Can I monitor the actual stack size being used (using JvisualVm or any other tool)?

2) Can I estimate by the method stack (counting the amount of methods in the current executing thread) what is the required stack size per thread so I will not get the StackOverFlowError?

Comment: Are you certain that you don't have an infinite recursion in your code?  I think you should investigate this before increasing the stack size.

Comment: I'm sure that I don't have  an infinite recursion. When I increase the stack size (-Xss). Everything works well. But this is an Enterprise product and the load in constantly changing by the users. So, i need to figure out some rules that will tell the users what should be the stack size according to the load (I guess the depth of the call stack)....

Comment: _Ad 2)_ In the byte code every method specifies the stack frame size for the local variables it needs. _Ad 1)_ So from a stack trace, you might get these infos: which methods involved, how often and local variable usage. Recursion using an integer parameter to loop, or using a sublist, should be made nicer. - So do a code analysis by the stack trace.

Comment: A poor man's way to count the number of method invocations would be to log each call.  If this would result in too massive a log file, you could keep some global state, e.g. in a singleton, which would be incremented at each method entry.

Comment: @JoopEggen the StackOverFlowError includes the ful stack (all the method till the the point the exception happend) = until the point i've reached 1 MB of stack usage. My question is: assuming I increase the stack size to 2 MB, does it mean that I can have stack twice bigger (twice as much method calls) without having the exception?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I already have the full stack trace,I want some accurate data on the stack usage.

Comment: Yes, you could increase the stack, but it is a bit like memory leakage: for instance if a recursive `File.listFiles` was done, a bit of rewriting would reduce stack usage tremendously. Also using `findbugs` to detect problematic code is something one should try. Stack overflow on correct code is absolutely rare. A 1000x1000 recursion? Check the methods